# Atomically create a file at a filesystem path

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, atomic, c++20

What is the idiomatic way to *atomically* create a file at a path, even if intermediate elements in the path do not exist?

For example, given a directory that looks like this

```
$ tree one
one
├── two
└── three
```

I want to write a string to the file at path "one/four/five/six" atomically.

In this context, by "atomic" I mean -- if the write fails, I don't want the path `one/four` to exist. If the write succeeds, I want the whole path `one/four/five/six` to be valid and have the string that I wrote to it. I *do not* care about a durability guarantee after the write, so I *do not* care about  "if the write succeeds, then the file must be present at the given path even in the event of a power failure".

Looking for an implementation in standard C++ (so anything using `std::filesystem` or `ofstream` would be nice, but not required, I can use the regular POSIX API if I have to).

Comment: There is no way to do this atomically as it requires multiple operations. You'd have to implement it yourself and clear up after any errors. If you've got multiple threads you'll need a mutex. If other processes are also performing operations then i don't think there is any way to do this safely

Comment: @AlanBirtles I guess I was looking for the steps needed in such an implementation. How would I even go about implementing this? For example, could I use some sort of directory rename facility to do this?

Comment: Yes, I think you can build up everything in a temporary directory, and then `rename` it to `four`.  That's atomic on POSIX, and `std::filesystem::rename` is specified to work "as if by POSIX `rename`", so in principle it should be atomic too.

Comment: If you go with Nate Eldredge's idea, keep in mind the temporary directory has to be in the same file system (or even mount point). See EXDEV in rename(2).

Comment: @NateEldredge does rename atomically move the entire parent directory tree to the new directory as well?

Comment: @Curious: `rename("one-tmp/four", "one/four")` causes the directory `four` to now appear under `one`.  The contents of `four` remain unchanged, and so they still appear within `four` which now has a new name.  So the effect is as if the entire tree was moved, but really nothing happened to any of the files or directories within `four`.  Such a rename is not a heavy operation and the system has no trouble doing it atomically.

Comment: Under the hood, at least on a traditional Unix-like filesystem, the directory known as `one-tmp/four` has an inode, call it 12345, describing all its contents. Directory `one-tmp` contains an entry named `four` which points to inode 12345. When you `rename("one-tmp/four", "one/four")`, the directory entry in `one-tmp` is removed and a new entry is created in `one`, also named `four` and again pointing to inode 12345.  But inode 12345 and its contents do not change at all.  So it's just a matter of atomically removing one directory entry and creating another.